# python create multiple year daterange with specific end date for every year

Tags: python, pandas, date, range

Hello need some help with this problem

`a = pd.date_range(start="2001-01-01", freq="T", periods=520000)`

This creates the date-range  i need for 1 year. I want to do the same for the next 80 years. The end result should be a date range for 80year but every year ends after 520000min. Then i add the date range to my dataset.

Comment: there is missing data at the end of every year (like3 days).  Maybe it is better to fill the missing data with 0  and use full year

Comment: I think you can create a loop to append but I think your comment is better cause further down, there are gaps and I wonder if you later algo will have problem with that.

Comment: yes there will be more problems at then end probably i will add 0s

Comment: Why do you specify both `freq` and `periods` ? You want the first 520000 minutes of every year ? Or every minutes of the 80 years ?

Answer (score -1):

```
# this is the data
ALL_Data = pd.DataFrame({"Lebensverbrauch_Min": LebensverbrauchMIN,
                             "HPT": Heisspunkttemperatur_Sim1,
                             "Innentemperatur": StartS,
                             "Verlustleistung": V_Leistung,
                            "SolarEintrag": SolarEintrag,
                            "Lastfaktor": K_Load_Faktor
                             })

# How many minutes are left in the year
    DatenJahr = len(pd.date_range(start=str(xx) + "-01-01", freq="T", periods=520000))
    VollesJahr = len(pd.date_range(start=str(xx) + "-01-01", freq="T", end=str(xx + 1) + "-01-01"))
    GG = (VollesJahr - DatenJahr)
    d = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((GG, 6)), columns=['Lebensverbrauch_Min', 'HPT', 'Innentemperatur','Verlustleistung',
                                                'SolarEintrag', 'Lastfaktor',])
#combine Data with 0
    ALL_Data = pd.concat([ALL_Data, d])
```

seems to work but the complete code needs 4h to run so we will see

Comment: In English please?

Comment: @Keldorn: This is in English. The data and variable names aren’t, but that’s independent of the functionality. The comments and explanation are in English.

Comment: True, but variable names help reading the program, which reduces the effort needed to understand your program. If you don't make an effort to make it easy to help you, I won't make an effort to read your program and help you. YMMV.

Comment: can do it in english next time. It worked.

Comment: Ok. 4 hours to get a few millions variables sounds like 3 or 4 orders of magnitude slower than what I'd expect, but if it works for you it's all good.